# How to display TextView and EditText in one line in Android?

Tags: java, android

This may seem very simple to most of you but I am struggling with one thing since a little while. 
I created a form on Android studio and I am trying to display the entered values in one single line once a button is clicked but I can't. Can anybody help me?

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Server Address:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/server"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter server here..."
    android:text="xx.ku315.com:"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Server Port:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/port"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter port here..."
    android:text="11111"
    />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter password here..."
    android:text="123456@"
    />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Encryption Method:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/method"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="aes-256-cfb:"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Encode"/>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Base64 Code:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/b64"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:editable="false"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Copy code"/>
</LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the java side

```
package com.example.cedric.trial;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText server_address, server_port, server_password, b64_code;
TextView encrypt_method;
Button enc_btn, act_btn;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    server_address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.server);
    server_port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
    server_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    b64_code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b64);
    encrypt_method = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.method);
    enc_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    enc_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            b64_code.setText(encrypt_method.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    act_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear, can you add more explanation for your problem ?

Comment: Once i click on the button i want to display like
server_address:server_port:server_password:encrypt_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LinearLayout parent has a vertical orientation, so its children are stacked on top of each other like so:

```
TextView
EditText
TextView
EditText
etc
```

If you want to center them you can add

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

to the linearlayout.

If you want them to be in one horizontal like so

```
TextView EditText TextView EditText
```

then change orientation in your LinearLayout to

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

and to align them equally change LinearLayout gravity to:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

However if you want this layout:

```
TextView EditText
TextView EditText
TextView EditText
Button
```

Then you need to do it like so

```
LinearLayout vertical
  LinearLayout horizontal
    TextView EditText
  LinearLayout horizontal
    TextView EditText
  LinearLayout horizontal
    TextView EditText
  Button
```

Edit

if you just want to display the values then get all the strings and then concat them with ":" between them. like so:

```
    String serverAddress = server_address.getText.toString();
    String serverPort = server_port.getText.toString();
    String password = server_password.getText.toString();
    String encryptMethod = encrypt_method.getText.toString();

b64_code.setText(serverAddress.concat(":").concat(serverPort).concat(":").concat(password).concat(":").concat(encryptMethod));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what i want exactly is the action when the button is clicked, i want it to be displayed like: encrypt_method:server_password:server_address:server_port.
The appearance is not my biggest concern, the output when the button is clicked is

Comment: ok, it sounded like you wanted your layout that way, I updated my answer